# Simple Elementary algebra

Tags: arithmetic

Kelly peeked around the corner and spied $540$ of them not studying. If this was $50\%$ more than Chris spied, how many did Chris spy?

My answer was $270$ and marked incorrect. Why?

Please help explain. Thank you!

Comment: If Chris spied $270$ and Kelly spied $540$, then Kelly would have actually spied $100\%$ more (*of an amount that Chris spied*) than Chris did, not $50\%$.  When talking about percentages, it is imperative to keep track of *what the percentages are of*.

Comment: Although, if Chris spied $270$ and Kelly spied $540$, then Kelly would have spied $50\%$ more *of an amount that Kelly spied* than Chris did, this is not how the sentence is generally interpreted when the clarification of what the percentage is of is omitted.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Post this as the answer. Yes, it's elementary, but it's what the OP needs.

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated :) lots of help everyone. I hate word problems:/ I always have difficulty interpreting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ratios

$540 : 150\%$

$x  : 100\%$ (True number)

Drawing an X yields

$\dfrac{540\cdot100}{150} = 360$

Answer (score 0):

Say Chris has spied on $x$ people, "50% more than x is 540" translates to:
$$\dfrac{150}{100}\cdot x = 540$$Get $x$ as subject of the formula and you get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've worked out as if Kelly spied 100% more than Chris spied.  50% more isn't double. It's half as much again.

You want:

$540=\frac{150}{100}\times C$

$C=540\times \frac{2}{3}=360$